# Cannot change variable in batch script conditionally

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

This batch script always gives the answer "You make some 0" instead of other options.
What did I do wrong here?

```
set /a foodcalc=0
set /a dish=0
set /a food1=1   
set /a food2=2    
set /a food3=3    
set /a food4=4    
SET /a foodcalc=4*%random%/32768+1    
IF foodcalc==1 set /a dish food1    
IF foodcalc==2 set /a dish food2    
IF foodcalc==3 set /a dish food3    
IF foodcalc==4 set /a dish food4
echo You make some %dish%.    
ping localhost -n 3 >nul    
goto actualgame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF %foodcalc%==1 set /a dish=food1
IF %foodcalc%==2 set /a dish=food2
IF %foodcalc%==3 set /a dish=food3
IF %foodcalc%==4 set /a dish=food4
```

Answer (score 2):

need to use % to refer back to the contents of a variable, this way

```
     if %foodcalc%==1 echo one!
```